# How to make a select query in crystal report

Tags: sql, vb6, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7, VB6 and SQL

In the Crysal Report, I want to display a column from SQL Select Query

In crystal Report, Where can i add the query, then how can i add the column from the select query.

For ex

```
In Crystal Report, i want to enter Select * from table where dates = '" & sdate &"'
In VB6, I want to pass the sdate value to crystal report
Then crystal report Should display the column for selected date.
```

Can any one suggest me, how to do it.

Need Crystal Report Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Crystal Reportts 7, you can't. You can only use the visual query builder to join tables together; you can then drag and drop fields into your report.

Alternatively, you can create your query as a view in your database, then add the view to your report.